# derived class not needing some of the parent methods or attributes

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, extends

Is it possible and logical that a derived class does not need some of the methods or attributes of its parent class?

For example,

```
public class FinishedCourse extends Course{
  ...
}
```

FinishedCourse class which is derived from Course class, but *does not need some of the methods or attributes of Course class*

Comment: Absolutely yes, But by logic parent class should contains methods and properties that will be hared by multiple derived classes and If your derived class doesn't need a lot of derived class properties and methods will be something illogical.

Comment: Not quite: inheritance is usually for objects that specialize / deepen the parent; in your simple example it looks more like a Course is a *specialization* of a FinishedCourse - but of course finished / unfinished can be a *status*, so the example is really too simple.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan some private variables for example.

Comment: @Sherl: If the variables are private, the subclass doesn't see them anyway. (They're there, the subclass just can't see them.) But that's not what your *question* asks. The "private" part is a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do with this. But I think this will clear up the things for you.

```
public class Course{
  private String course = "CS101";
}


public class FinishedCourse extends Course{

  public void displayCourse(){

    System.out.println(super.course); //compilation error. 
    //You cannot access private variables even if it is in direct parent class
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's neither possible nor logical.

**Possible**: No. When you create a subclass, it inherits all of the public (and protected) attributes of the parent class. (It also inherits the private bits, but it cannot access them.) While you could override some methods with something that throws an exception to indicate that it's no longer relevant ([`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)), the subclass will still have the method, and in some circles that may be viewed subjectively as poor design. (In other circles, it may be viewed subjectively as pragmatic.)

**Logical**: No. A subclass has an "is a" relationship with its superclass. You can use a `FinishedCourse` anywhere a `Course` is expected, and in fact the code using the instance may well not know (or care) that it's dealing with a subclass rather than with `Course`.

Instead, a couple of options:

1. You could have a base class that implements only what `FinishedCourse` needs (perhaps `BaseCourse`), and have `FinishedCourse` and `Course` both subclass it. When a course is finished, create a `FinishedCourse` instance to replace the `Course` instance.
2. Have a `Course` just contain course information, and separately have a `CourseHandler` object that knows how to handle courses that are in-progress.
3. Probably any of several other ways of going about it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible and logical that a derived class does not need some of
>   the methods or attributes of its parent class?

If a method is defined in the parent class, generally the subclasses of it should have some use case to use it.

Making a class inherit a method that will never be used is often a problem of design as the API doesn't suit to its needs.
**It makes the class intention not clear and error prone.**

This kind of design may appear when the inheritance is improperly used.
For example when we use inheritance to make inherit methods and not to make inherit a class/concept.

Now, it is perfectly valid that a method of a parent class be overriden by a subclass and that this overriden methods doesn't rely at all on the super method (method of parent class).